# PHP Convert Array Including Key Rename

Tags: php, arrays, key

I need convert this PHP array from a `$_POST['tags']` output

```
$_POST = array('title' => 'apple','content' => 'fruit', 'tags' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 11, 3 => 13));
```

I need this part converted

```
[tags] => Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 11 [3] => 13 ) )
```

into the following format and then push it back into `$_POST['tags']`

```
[tags] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tag_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [tag_id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [tag_id] => 11 ) [3] => Array ( [tag_id] => 13 )
```

I've tried but it doesn't work ...

```
$returnArray['tags'] = array();
foreach($_POST['tags'] as $t)
{
    $tags = array();
    $tags['tag_id'] = $t['tag_id'];
    array_push($returnArray['tags'], $tags);
}
unset($_POST['tags']);
$_POST['tags'] = array();
array_push($_POST['tags'] , $returnArray);
```

im on PHP Version 5.2.17

Comment: Why do you need to push it back into the `$_POST` superglobal? This sounds like a terrible idea and is something the next developer who has to use the codebase will hunt you down for in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Use `array_map` and assign the `key` -

```
$new = array_map(function($v) {
    return array('tag_id' => $v);
}, $_POST['tags']);
```

Comment: do i replace $your_array with $_POST['tags'] ? and $new add to ... $_POST['tags'] =  $new; ... sorry a little confused.

Comment: Check the update. `$new` will be your expected array. Then you can use it.

Comment: Thanks, can the script run inside a if conditional statement? I pasted your code and i get a blank page ... i guess it breaks it. if(isset($_POST['tags'])){ }

Comment: Im on PHP Version 5.2.17   ... not sure if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it

```
$returnArray['tags'] = array();
foreach($_POST['tags'] as $t)
{
    $tags = array();
    $tags['tag_id'] = $t;
    array_push($returnArray['tags'], $tags);
}
$_POST['tags'] = $returnArray;
```

Comment: thanks but I get this result: 
[tags] => Array ( [tags] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [tag_id] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [tag_id] => 2 ) [2] => Array ( [tag_id] => 11 ) [3] => Array ( [tag_id] => 13 ) ) ) ) ... with two [tags] need to remove the first array tag

Comment: Here the full array that needs tags part formatted. $_POST = array( 'question' => 'what is windows 8?', 'status' => 1, 'website_id' => '', 'notes' => 'this is faq note', 'content' => 'this is OS', 'tags' => array(0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 11, 3 => 13));